# Vue 3: Why changing a prop of a watched object in the watch handler doesn't create infinite loop?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'd expect that this code would create an infinite loop since the object that is watched is changed in the watch handler:

```js
const App = {
  setup() {

    const state = Vue.reactive({
      name: "",
      message: "Welcome stranger"
    });

    Vue.watch(state, () => state.message = `Hello ${state.name}`);

    return state;
  }
};

Vue.createApp(App).mount("#root");
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<div id="root">
  name: <input v-model="name"/> <br/>
  message: {{ message }}
</div>
```

But it actually works as desired. I'm really surprised.

Does doing it like this have some performance penalty or is it a completely valid code?

Comment: I think it works because once the `message` is updated, the watched object isn't *changed* any more. You are effectively updating the `message` twice for each `name` change, after that nothing more is changing.

Comment: so it runs twice and because the second time the *changed* value is the same? Are you saying  that Vue checks the changed value and rerenders only if it's different?

Answer (score 0):

As @slauth pointed out this works because Vue checks if the changed value is different that the previous and doesn't trigger updates if the value didn't change. This can be shown by logging each time the handler is fired:

```js
const App = {
  setup() {

    const state = Vue.reactive({
      name: "",
      message: "Welcome stranger"
    });

    Vue.watch(state, () => {
      console.log("watch handler fired for", state.name);
      state.message = `Hello ${state.name}`;
    });

    return state;
  }
};

Vue.createApp(App).mount("#root");
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<div id="root">
  name: <input v-model="name" /> <br/> message: {{ message }}
</div>
```

This means that the watch handler is called twice for each dependency change. So although it works it has a performance cost.